# Create a new guest account and then inviting the guest account to a SharePoint site is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, external-sharing, guest-access

We have a SharePoint site named "tgbtgb" which only allow sharing with existing guests, as follow:-

[image]

Now we wanted to invite a new external user. so we did these steps:-

1. Inside azure portal we create a new guest account as follow:-

[image]

2. then once the account got created (before the user access the invitation link) >> we add the external user to a SharePoint group under the above site >> where the user got directly added to the SharePoint group.
3. now the external user got 2 emails, as follow:-

[image]

&

[image]

now the external user accept the first invitation and got registered as guest. but the second email, had no link to the site, as the site name tgbtgb is not clickable! + also when the user try to navigate to the site by typing the site url inside the browser, the user got this error message:-

[image]

although when i checked the external user permission inside the SharePoint site >> i got that the user already have Edit permission as follow:-

[image]

so not sure what is going on? why the user can not access the site he has edit permission on ? also when the invitation email has the site title as UN-clickable?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're attempting to use Azure AD B2B integration with SharePoint Online for the management of guests but you may not have completed some of the initial configuration required. I would read the following article and decide if you do want to use Azure AD B2B for the management of SharePoint Online guests.

[SharePoint and OneDrive integration with Azure AD B2B](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-azureb2b-integration)

To enable this integration, you will need to run the following PowerShell cmdlets against your SharePoint Online tenant:

```
Set-SPOTenant -EnableAzureADB2BIntegration $true
Set-SPOTenant -SyncAadB2BManagementPolicy $true
```